# Slider Image with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem with a small jQuery script that my slide images. The script itself works very well, but I would like to add link for each image, already try to place `<a href>` and the `</a>` tags on each side of the `<img>` but it doesn't work.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="/images/main_banner01.jpg" border="0">
    <img src="/images/main_banner02.jpg" border="0">
    <img src="/images/main_banner03.jpg" border="0">
    <img src="/images/main_banner04.jpg" border="0">
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript">

$(function(){

    var p=$('#content').responsiveSlides({
        height:484,                     // slides conteiner height
        background:'#fff',              // background color and color of overlayer to fadeout on init
        autoStart:true,                 // boolean autostart
        startDelay:0,                   // start whit delay
        effectInterval:5000,            // time to swap photo
        effectTransition:1000,          // time effect
        pagination:[
            {
                active:true,            // activate pagination
                inner:true,             // pagination inside or aouside slides conteiner
                position:'B_L',         /* 
                                            pagination align:
                                                T_L = top left
                                                T_C = top center
                                                T_R = top right

                                                B_L = bottom left
                                                B_C = bottom center
                                                B_R = bottom right
                                        */
                margin:10,              // pagination margin
                dotStyle:'',            // dot pagination class style
                dotStyleHover:'',       // dot pagination class hover style
                dotStyleDisable:''      // dot pagination class disable style
            }
        ]
    });

});
</script>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.responsiveSlides = function(options){
        var _this=this;
        var _int=null;
        var im=' !important';
        var settings = $.extend({
            img:null,
            height:$(_this).height(),
            background:'#fff',
            loadingClassStyle:'',
            autoStart:true,
            startDelay:0,
            effectInterval:5000,
            effectTransition:1000,
            pagination:[{active:true, inner:true, position:'B_C', margin:10, dotStyle:'', dotStyleHover:'', dotStyleDisable:''}]
        },options);
        _this.RS_Start=function(){
            _this.RS_Stop();
            _int=setInterval(function(){
                var n=$('.current',$('.tgtimg',_this)).next('img');
                if(n.length==0){
                    n=$('img:first',$('.tgtimg',_this));
                }
                _this.RS_ShowPhoto(n);
            },settings.effectInterval);
        };
        _this.RS_Stop=function(){clearInterval(_int); _int=null;}
        _this.RS_ShowPhoto=function(next){
            $('.current',$('.tgtimg',_this)).fadeOut(settings.effectTransition);
            next.fadeIn(settings.effectTransition,function(){
                $('.current',$('.tgtimg',_this)).removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
                var std=settings.pagination[0].dotStyleDisable;
                if(std!=''){
                    $('.'+std,$('.pagination',_this)).removeClass(std);
                    $('div:eq('+$(this).index()+')',$('.pagination',_this)).addClass(std);
                }else{
                    $('div',$('.pagination',_this)).css('opacity',1);
                    $('div:eq('+$(this).index()+')',$('.pagination',_this)).css('opacity',0.5);
                }
                if(_int==null&&settings.autoStart){_this.RS_Start();}
            });
        };
        //var overstyle='position:absolute'+im+'; height:100%'+im+'; width:100%'+im+'; text-align:center'+im+'; line-height:'+settings.height+'px'+im+'; z-index:2'+im+'; background:'+settings.background+im+';';
        var overstyle='position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center; line-height:'+settings.height+'px; z-index:2; background-color:'+settings.background+';';
        if(settings.loadingClassStyle==''){
            overstyle+='font-family:Arial'+im+'; ';
            if(settings.background.toLowerCase()=='#fff'||settings.background.toLowerCase()=='#ffffff'){
                overstyle+='color:#000'+im+';';
            }else{
                overstyle+='color:#fff'+im+';';
            }
        }
        var tgtstyle='position:absolute'+im+'; height:'+settings.height+'px'+im+'; width:100%'+im+'; background:'+settings.background+im+'; z-index:1'+im+'; overflow:hidden'+im;
        $(_this).height(settings.height).prepend('<div class="overslide '+settings.loadingClassStyle+'" style="'+overstyle+'">loading..</div><div class="tgtimg" style="'+tgtstyle+'"></div>');

        if(settings.img==null || settings.img==undefined || settings.img=='undefined'){
            $('img',_this).appendTo($('.tgtimg',_this));
            $('img',$('.tgtimg',_this)).each(function(i,e){
                $(this).attr('style','position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px; height:'+settings.height+'px; display:'+((i==0)?'block':'none'))
                if(i==0){
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $.each(settings.img,function(i,e){
                $('.tgtimg',_this).append('<img src="'+e+'" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px; height:'+settings.height+'px; display:'+((i==0)?'block':'none')+'" class="'+((i==0)?'current':'')+'">');
            });
        }
        $('img',$('.tgtimg',_this)).onImagesLoad(function(){
            // every images are loaded. can i init
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('img',$('.tgtimg',_this)).each(function(i,e){
                    var l=-(($(e).width()-$(_this).width())/2);
                    if($(_this).width()>$(e).width()){
                        l=($(_this).width()-$(e).width())/2;
                    }
                    $(e).css('left',l+'px');
                });
            }).trigger('resize');
            var p=settings.pagination[0];
            if(p.active){
                var pos=(p.position.substring(0,1)=='T')?'top:'+p.margin+'px; ':'bottom:'+p.margin+'px; ';
                pos+=(p.position.substring(2,3)=='L')?'left:'+p.margin+'px; ':(p.position.substring(2,3)=='R')?'right:'+p.margin+'px; ':'left:50%; ';
                var elm='';

                $('img',$('.tgtimg',_this)).each(function(i,e){elm+='<div'+((p.dotStyle=='')?' style="float:left; height:15px; width:15px; background:#fff; margin-left:2px; cursor:pointer"':' class="'+p.dotStyle+'"')+'></div>';});
                $(_this).append('<div class="pagination" style="position:absolute; z-index:10; '+pos+'">'+elm+'</div>');
                if(p.position.substring(2,3)=='C'){
                    $('.pagination',_this).css('margin-left','-'+parseInt($('.pagination',_this).width()/2)+'px');
                }else if(p.position.substring(2,3)=='R'){
                    $('.pagination',_this).css('margin-left','-'+($('.pagination',_this).width()+p.margin)+'px');
                }
                if(!p.inner){
                    $('.pagination',_this).css('margin-top',-$('.pagination',_this).height()-(p.margin*2)+'px');
                    $('.pagination',_this).css('margin-bottom',-$('.pagination',_this).height()-(p.margin*2)+'px');
                }
                $('div',$('.pagination',_this)).mouseover(function(){
                    if(p.dotStyleHover!=''){$(this).addClass(p.dotStyleHover);}else{$(this).css('background','#CCC');}
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    if(p.dotStyleHover!=''){$(this).removeClass(p.dotStyleHover);}else{$(this).css('background','#fff');}
                }).click(function(){
                    _this.RS_Stop();
                    _this.RS_ShowPhoto($('img:eq('+$(this).index()+')',$('.tgtimg',_this)));
                });
            }
            // init transition after delay and remove overlayer whit custom bg color
            $('.overslide',_this).delay(settings.startDelay).fadeOut(settings.effectTransition,function(){
                if(settings.autoStart){_this.RS_Start();}
                $('div:eq(0)',$('.pagination',_this)).css('opacity',0.5);
            });
        });
        return _this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Any idea ? Thank you all :)

Comment: create to jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this 
Create a attribute to store your url for that image, using windows.location navigate to tat page
html:

```
<div id="content">
    <img data-href="/url1" src="/images/main_banner01.jpg" border="0">
    <img data-href="/url2" src="/images/main_banner02.jpg" border="0">
    <img data-href="/url3" src="/images/main_banner03.jpg" border="0">
    <img data-href="/url4" src="/images/main_banner04.jpg" border="0">
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#content img').click(function(){
 window.location =$(this).attr('data-href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use data-href attribute to each of your image element where you want to target.

```
<img src="/images/main_banner01.jpg" data-href='#' border="0">
```

And in js file you need to add following code to target on click event on image

```
$('#content img').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

So now on click you can target to your data-href attribute of selected image.